# My application Stopped while am using this code to select some items using an id

Tags: android, sqlite

This is my DatabaseHandler class where i add my select code

[image]

This is my error

[image: This is my activity where try to select item]

Comment: Please post the code directly to the question (not as images).

Comment: Check my updated answer

Comment: Images and screenshots can be a nice addition to a post, but please make sure the post is still clear and useful without them. **Don't post images of code or error messages.** Read [why](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) Instead copy and paste or type the actual code/message into the post directly.

Answer (score 0):

**Replace line**

```
if(tagId != "")
```

**with**

```
if(!tagId.equals(""))
```